# Java Multiplying

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

I am creating a minecraft plugin based on the movie InTime and am trying to create code that on death of the player the player will lose 25% of their time.

Current code is:

```
String minus = itapi.getTimeString(player.getName());
itapi.removeTime(player.getName(), itapi.getDeathTime());
ItemStack book = itapi.createTimeCard("Death of " + player.getName(), minus, 1);
itapi.removeTime(player.getName(), minus * 0.25);
e.getDrops().add(book);
```

Though line 4 flags "`The operator * is undefined for the argument type(s) String, double`"

I know it is probally a real simple fix but im out of ideas any suggestions?

`TimeString` has to be a `string`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot multiply a `String` by anything.  You'll need to convert it to a `double`, then multiply it with [`Double.parseDouble`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29):

```
Double.parseDouble(minus) * 0.25
```

Make sure to handle any `NumberFormatExceptions` if `minus` can't be represented as a number.

Answer (score 1):

You defined `minus` as a String, then do String * a double.  You cannot multiply a String times a double.  Convert the TimeString to an actual value, like a int seconds, then you can do math on it.